# Unity: C#: Eyes look at mouse: How do I proceed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cursor, game-physics, mouseover

I have a character in a 2D game, my goal is to get his eyes look as if they are looking at the cursor by moving the circles used for pupils towards the cursor, with limits. I have been stuck trying to create this for two days now and have yet to find a way that works!!
Using the following code I was able move my eyes towards the cursor, however this only works around the bottom left of the screen! (If the cursor is not below the screen or to the left of the screen the eyes move to the top right)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LookAtMouse : MonoBehaviour {


    public float speed = 5f;
    private Vector3 target;
    public Transform origin;

    void Start () {
        target = transform.position;


    }

    void Update () {

            target = (Input.mousePosition);
            target.z = transform.position.z;

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(origin.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }   
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be incredibly grateful! 
Thank you :)

Comment: Have you got it working without limits first?

Comment: Hey, thanks for reading!
@ Jashaszun ;)

@OMGtechy
Not yet, that's why I posted this, it only moves around the bottom left corner of the screen.

Comment: Bottom left would be third quadrant, where is the origin at? Center of screen or left hand side, top or bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the reason it's only working in one quadrant for you is because `Input.mousePosition` returns a position in pixel coordinates. Basically, if your window is 800x600 pixels, it will return...

(0, 0, 0) for the *bottom left pixel* of the screen

(0, 600, 0) for the *top left pixel* of the screen

(800, 0, 0) for the *bottom right pixel* of the screen

(800, 600, 0) for the *top right pixel* of the screen

Since your eye pupil is in world space, you want the mouse position in world space also. Either way, even if you fixed that, I don't think `Vector3.MoveTowards` is going to do quite what you're wanting to do. I think this is more along the lines of what you want:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtMouse : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 5f;
    public float maxDistance = 1f;

    public Camera mainCamera;
    private Vector3 _origin;

    void Start () { 
        _origin = transform.position;
    }

    void Update () {

        /* Get the mouse position in world space rather than screen space. */
        var mouseWorldCoord = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition).origin;

        /* Get a vector pointing from initialPosition to the target. Vector shouldn't be longer than maxDistance. */
        var originToMouse = mouseWorldCoord - _origin;
        originToMouse = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(originToMouse, maxDistance);

        /* Linearly interpolate from current position to mouse's position. */
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, _origin + originToMouse, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But after implementing the script it gives the error, the type camera does not have a definition for screen point to ray.

Comment: That script is just expecting you to drop in a normal Unity Camera object in the inspector on that script. Are you using another type of Camera (say from NGUI or 2D Toolkit)? And are you also making sure to include UnityEngine?

If you look at the Unity docs, `ScreenPointToRay()` is a method for the Camera type: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html

Comment: Also make sure you're calling the `ScreenPointToRay` on the Camera *instance* (which I called mainCamera in the script, you can give it a different name), rather than the *type*, which would be `Camera` starting with a capital c.

Comment: Your script works perfectly! I had created a script called Camera which was confusing the script :)
Thank you so much!